# loopback connector to MySQL does not close

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud

I am presently using an application in the platform IBM Bluemix, that requires a MySQL database.

I decided to use a MySQL database (experimental support), supporting a max of 10 concurrent connections.

The problem is that if I restart my app 10 times (through cf restart, or using the dashboard), it will be impossible to run and the logs clearly say I am using the max amount (10) of connections.

The problem, thus, is that either connections are not closed when the app is stopped, or when it is (re)started, it does not use the already existing MySQL link.

At this point, I am not sure about what to do. Can anyone help?

EDIT
versions : I have used loopback-connector-mysql 2.2.0 and loopback-datasource-juggler@2.41.0

Comment: Something wrong here. If you exit your application, the peer will close all its connections. Are you trying to run 10 instances at the same time?

Comment: EJP : it seems that the connection is not closed by the peer, even if I have only one application.

Comment: I've seen similar behavior with a loopback applications where a utility script (automigrate for example) will not close unless you do an explicit `process.exit(0)`, which I usually precede with an explicit `mysqlDS.disconnect()`. Depends on how your code is structured.

Comment: I think there is a part of the problem. When through the dashboard I delete an app, services are stopped, and that's all. If the database was used, the connection is not closed a priori.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution,

After contacting the support, the time before closing is 28800 (that means 8 hours), and they won't change it. However, I managed to go through this problem by changing the application, in files such as datasource.js where I set the "connectionLimit" to 3 instead of 9. Switching from mysql experimental to clearDB MySQL is also a valid option.

Comment: how do you change the mysql connection limit? and how to know which mysql (experimental, cleardb, etc stuff) the app is using, and what are the available values for that? I hope you could point me to some doc or link where I could find them. Thanks!

Comment: Also, how does reducing the connection limit help? does it mean that if you restart the app, it will force close the previous connections? thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact answer you are looking for, but is workaround.

You can set up timeout in MySQL configuration, so MySQL close the connection if connection is idle for some time.

Please refer to this document
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Probably you will need to set something like:

```
wait_timeout = 120 # 2 minutes
interactive_timeout  = 120 # 2 minutes
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try to do this. However, databases are seen in bluemix as APIs and services, that means it is normally impossible to edit the parameters of the database

Comment: i am speaking about server master configuration, e.g my.cnf